# Extended Domino Dots

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, string, number

### Introduction

Classes have started! And so does the boredom. I decided to doodle in my notebook and started to draw some dots in (IMO) an aesthetically pleasing way. I came up with these numbers:
[image: Dot Numbers]

based on these conditions: 
Given (n, m) 
1) There must be *n* dots 
2) All dots must lie on an *m* by *m* lattice 
3) The position of the dots must minimize the spread* from the top left corner 
4) The configuration of the dots must be diagonally symmetric as pictured: 
[image: Symmetry Example]

*Spread (in this context) is defined as the sum of the distances from the top left dot position (whether or not there is a dot there). For example, the spread of the example above is 0 + 1 + 2 + 1 + √2 + 2 + 2√2 = 6 + 3√2

### The Challenge

Come up with an algorithm using that uses *natural numbers* n and m (where it will always be that n <= m^2) to *generate* a configuration of dots that follow all the rules above.

**Input** can be received via STDIN, command-line argument, or function parameter.

**Output** the pattern to STDOUT or return a string with newlines. Any two different characters may be used in the output.
(e.g.

```
110
100
000
```

is the same as

```
**-
*--
---
```

**Shortest Code in Bytes Wins**

### Example

STDIN: `6 3` 
STDOUT:

```
***
**_
*__
```

## The Challenge has Ended!!!

After seven days I decided to declare the winner, but first some special awards! 
Fastest code goes to... orlp with his submission in Pyth ! 
Slowest code goes to... orlp with his submission in Pyth ! 
Most straightforward code goes to... orlp with his submission in Pyth ! 
Most confusing code goes to... orlp with his submission in Pyth ! 
Longest Code goes to... orlp with his submission in Pyth !

### And last but not least

**Shortest code goes to......... orlp with his submission in Pyth !**

Congratulations!

Comment: I updated the conditions so that 10 3 will never be an input. Also 0 is not a natural number so 0 0 will also never be an input

Comment: *natural numbers* is ambiguous. The set-theoretic definition of natural number, e.g., includes **0**. To avoid confusion, it's preferable to use *(strictly) positive integers*.

Comment: @Dennis Also, if one specifically wants to include zero, _nonnegative integers_ are a good choice.

Comment: What if there there are several valid solutions? E.g. `24 6`.

Comment: @steveverrill I think they're sqrt(1^2+2^2)=sqrt(5)

Comment: @MartinBüttner Kudos for finding a case with two solutions! In such cases, just one solution is enough.

Comment: @KoreanwGlasses finding these cases isn't too hard. `24 6` is just the first case where you can put two dots on a diagonal which corresponds to a [Pythagorean triple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Pyth, 37 bytes

```
jc:*d*QQiRQhos.aMNf.Am}_dTT.c^UQ2vzNQ
```

Slow solution. Generates all possible pairs of [0, m), generate all possible n-combinations of those pairs (without repetition). Filter each combination of pairs such that if P is in the combination, so is `reverse(P)`. This guarantees diagonal symmetry. Sort by the sum of distances to the origin. Decode the pairs of numbers as base-m numbers, giving a list of indices. Create a string of spaces except for those indices, putting quotation marks instead. Finally chop into m pieces and join by newlines. Creates outputs like such:

```
""""
"""
""
"
```